# I need to send multiple users monthly invoices using crystal reports and logicity as auto emails

Tags: crystal-reports, mass-emails

is there any way to send multiple emails of invoice reports using one crystal report.

I am facing the issue like i have to send multiple emails for each user.

Thanks in advance.
Ajay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i just (FIO) figured it out but generating reports and saving to local drive 
rather then sending emails to you which is time consumption.

// cs file method.

```
  //0. Setting Up controller
                OpsManagementController OM = new OpsManagementController();

                //1. Getting Users List:
                var result = OM.GetUsersforInvoice();

                //2. Creating folder for Invoices:
                string folderName = @"D:\Google Drive\MonthlyInvoices";
                string fileName = ("Invoices_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy").ToString());
                string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, fileName);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);

                //3. Generating invoices by user name:
                for (int i = 0; i < result.UserDetail.Count; i++)
                {
                    var userId = result.UserDetail[i].UserID;
                    var userName = result.UserDetail[i].FullName;
                    userName = userName.Replace(@"C\O", "CO");
                    userName = userName.Replace(@"C/O", "CO");

                    report2.SetParameterValue("UserID", result.UserDetail[i].UserID);
                    report2.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, "D:/Google Drive/MonthlyInvoices/" + fileName + "/" + userName + ".pdf");
                }
```

contact please, if you need help.